# LGB Scoping Rule and Using "self" in Python

Tags: python

```
str2 = "Global"

class InClass:
 str2 = "Class"
 def Set(self, msg):
  self.str2 = msg
 def Print(self):
  print(str2)

g = InClass()
g.Set("Instance")
g.Print()
```

If I run this code, I get "Global" as result. But I cannot understand why.

By calling Set() method of instance g, variable str2 is now in the namespace of instance g. Then, following LGB scoping rule, the namespace of instance g is the first namespace where str2 can be found! So, the result should be "Instance".

Is this wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "LGB scoping"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` and `self.__class__` are *never* implicitly searched during scope resolution in Python.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't how this works. `print(str2)` from inside the method accesses the global `str2`. To access the `str2` member, use `print(self.str2)`.

Read this [SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) for the full details. An excerpt [from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules/292002#292002):

> At any time during execution, there
>   are at least three nested scopes whose
>   namespaces are directly accessible:
>   the innermost scope, which is searched
>   first, contains the local names; the
>   namespaces of any enclosing functions,
>   which are searched starting with the
>   nearest enclosing scope; the middle
>   scope, searched next, contains the
>   current module's global names; and the
>   outermost scope (searched last) is the
>   namespace containing built-in names.

This doesn't include the class members, so you have to refer to them explicitly with `self`.

Answer (score 0):

because you have define str2 = "Global" that python interpreter takes default.i agree with Eli.if you want to print then you have to explicitly print(self.str2) for accessing class variable str2 = "Class"

print g.str2  (will give you Class as output)